# Filter posts by month in ACF custom date picker field

Tags: wordpress, filtering, advanced-custom-fields

I have a date picker ACF custom field where user picks the event date when creating new post. I display all posts on a page and I order them by this event date. What I need is a filter option above the posts where you can pick the month to see only the events happening that month.
Here is my code:

```
<?
/*
*  Order Posts based on Date Picker value
*  this example expects the value to be saved in the format: yymmdd (JS) = Ymd (PHP)
*/

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;   
query_posts(array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'=>12,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date', // name of custom field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DSC',
    'pagination' => 'true',
    'cat' => '2'
));
?>

    <div class="filter">
        <a>January</a>
        <a>February</a>
        ...etc...
    </div>


<ul>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div>
                        <?php 
                            $date = get_field('event_date');
                            $dateformat = date("F j, Y", strtotime($date));
                        ?>
                        <p class="date"><?php echo $dateformat; ?> </p>
                        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    </div>
                </li>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'upcoming_events_order'); 
function upcoming_events_order( $query ) {
if( $query->is_post_type_archive('event') ) :
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => date('Ymd'), 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'DATE' ) ) );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value_num', 'DATE');
endif;    
};
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, how do I actually turn it into visible links with dates? I put it into functions.php and called a function in my template file, but it breaks the page.